# Feed command to Bash and get its output, via Pyte

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to write Python script, which runs Bash (on Linux) and catches its output with color  attributes, to [Pyte](https://github.com/selectel/pyte/) Screen object. Pyte has some examples. Example `nanoterm` shows how to run some process and put its output to Screen object. It doesn't work on Ubuntu x64 - script does nothing (I run it with "/bin/bash" param).

Maybe I need some other python library? I also cannot see how to put some command to new Bash. Eg `ls`. Pyte example cannot do it.